# Spacing between lines with bullets

Tags: vertical-alignment, lists, itemize

How to reduce spacing between lines with bullets?

```
\item[$\bullet$ Text1]
\item[$\bullet$] Text2
```

What command will include spacing between the lines generated by the above?

Comment: Why do you use `$\bullet$` explicitly? In an `itemize` environment, the bullets are there automatically

Comment: Because I want bullets in my text.

Comment: You don't need `$\bullet$` with `itemize`, see my answer please

Comment: How to align the text with bullets on the left side?

Comment: That's another question!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to use `itemsep` from `enumitem` with some negative values, to reduce the spacing. It holds for `itemize` as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=-5pt]
  \item First
  \item Second
\end{itemize}

\hrule

\vskip\baselineskip
Normal vertical separation

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[$\bullet$] First again
  \item[$\bullet$] Second
\end{itemize}
\columnbreak
\begin{itemize}
  \item First again
  \item Second
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

[image]